# Resume CountUp timer onClick of a button in onResume() method

Tags: android, timer, buttonclick, android-handler, onresume

I have 10 buttons on my fragment. I have a Count Up Timer "0:00:00" which counts up on first button click.

The count up timer works fine, It Pauses in the `OnPause()` and Resumes in the `onResume()` perfectly...

I want the timer to start on next **buttonclick** whenever the activity **resumes back.**

*My Runnable method in my MainActivity.java*

```
private static Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;
        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int hours = seconds / 3600;
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
    /*
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);  */


        textTimer.setText("" + String.format("%d", hours) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

My startTimer and my pauseTimer method

```
public static void startTimer() {
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
        //    textTimerValue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

public static void pauseTimer() {
    timeSwap += timeInMillies;
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
    timerValue = textTimer.getText().toString();
    Log.d(timerValue, "pause");
 //   textTimerValue.setText(timerValue);
}
```

My overridden methods

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, ACTIVITY_NAME+" onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    startTimer();
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, ACTIVITY_NAME+" onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    pauseTimer();
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, ACTIVITY_NAME+" onPause");
}
```

I want to *resume the timer* on the **next button click when the activity resumes after `onPause()`** not on `onResume()`..

My OnClickListener

```
 for (int i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
        final int b = i;
        bt[b] = (Button) v.findViewById(idArray[b]); //Fetch the view id from array

        bt[b].setEnabled(false);


        if (!bt[0].isEnabled()) {
            bt[0].setEnabled(true);
        }

        bt[b].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.bt0:
               if (click0 ==1) {
                       MainActivity.startTimer();
                        }

                     click0 = click0 + 1;
               if (click0 % 2 == 0) {
                       bt[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnew4);

               }

             }

    switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.bt1:
            // how to resume the timer on click of this button, if activity resumes from an onPause()
               click1 = click1 + 1;
               if (click1 % 2 == 0) {

           bt[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnew4);

       }
     }                 
     }
    }
```

I've tried to check `(if booleanOnPause == false)` in the `onClickListener()` before restarting the timer on each button click but the timer restarts on each button click as `booleanOnPause` is always false when the activity is active.

Comment: try to call onClick inside onResume and remove the startTimer there.

Comment: @Mike My buttons are in an array (question updated) how to call onClick inside onResume?

Comment: onClick(ButtonName);

Comment: With input from @Mike .. the best i could do was to add an AlertDialog inside onResume() now the timer resumes after the dialog box is cancelled by pressing OK button.. But I am still curious on how to solve my issue without the AlertDialog..